# Simplifications while deriving Jacobi Equation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, variational-calculus

The book I am referring to is, "**An Introduction to Lagrangian Mechanics by Alain J Brizard**".

My doubt is from Page number 5 of this book where the derivation of the Jacobi equation is done.

In the book, equation (1.8) is given as follows,

Let $F$ be a function $F(y, y',x)$, then;

$$\frac{d}{dx} \left(u^{'}\frac{\partial^2F }{(\partial y^{'})^2} +u \frac{\partial^2F}{{\partial y}{\partial y^{'}}}\right) = \left(u\frac{\partial^2F }{(\partial y)^2} +u^{'} \frac{\partial^2F}{{\partial y}{\partial y^{'}}}\right) \tag{1.8}$$

Here, in the book, they have written that they have found this by Taylor Expanding Euler's First Equation (Euler Lagrange equation), for $\bar y(x) = y(x) + u(x)$ where $\bar y$ and $y$ are solutions to Euler's first equation.

I am not getting how to do Taylor expansion of the following equation to get equation $(1.8)$.

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial y^{'}}\right) = \frac{\partial F}{\partial y}$$

I would be thankful if someone helps me solving this query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $y \to y+u$ then, to first order in $u,$  the LHS becomes
$$
\frac{\partial F}{\partial y'} \to \frac{\partial F}{\partial y'}+ u' \frac{\partial}{\partial y'}\left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial y'}\right) + u \frac{\partial }{\partial y}\left(\frac{\partial F} {\partial y'}\right)= \frac{\partial F}{\partial y'}+ u' \frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial y'^2}+ u \frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial y\partial y'}.
$$
The change in the RHS works in the same way, again with $\delta y=u$:
$$
\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}\to \frac{\partial F}{\partial y}+ u \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}\right) + u'  \frac{\partial}{\partial y'} \left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}\right)= \frac{\partial F}{\partial y}+ u  \frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial y^2} + u'  \frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial y'\partial y}.
$$
The only tricky thing is to remeber that $y$ and $y'$ are treated as independent variables in defining the the partial derivative, but $\delta (y')= (\delta y)'$.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? Have you done, Taylor expansion of partial derivative of F with respect to y’? Also, what to do about additional partial derivative of F with respect to y’ in RHS?

Comment: No elaboration is needed. It's just the same exansion one uses to derive the Lagrange equations: replace $\partial F/\partial y'$ by $L(y,y')$ to see this. I'll work out the RHS as again it is straightforward,

Comment: Got your point Mike, thank you.